# How do I have 629 GB of voice memos on a 128 GB iPhone?

Tags: ios, storage, settings

I'm trying to clear out my iPhone storage.  Settings says there's 629 GB of Documents & Data from Voice Memos.  I deleted the app, hoping it would get a reality check.  That didn't work.  Files shows nothing in Recently Deleted.  iCloud Drive is turned off.  iCloud backups are turned off.

How can I get my iPhone to think realistically about this?

[image: voice memos screenshot]

Comment: Why not open a support case with Apple. This surely is a bug…